# How to persist an entity without an ORM?

Tags: php, database, orm, repository, persistence

I'm trying to persist a domain model to a DB without using an ORM just for fun.

It's pretty easy to persist properties, but I'm having hard time persisting a collection.

Let's say I have the following two objects.

```
class aModel
{
    private $items = [];

    public function __construct($id, $name, array $items = [])
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->items = $items;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function addItem(Item $item)
    {
        $this->items[] = $item;
    }
}

class aDBRepository 
{
    public function persist(aModel $aModel)
    {
        $attributes = [
            'id' => $aModel->getId(),
            'name' => $aModel->getName()
        ];

        $this->table->insert($attributes);
    }
}
```

// Code

```
$aModel = new aModel("test id", "a name");
$aModel->addItem(new Item("id", "name"));
```

When I create a new **aModel** and add a new item to it, how do I detect 'unsaved' items and persist them?

I can only think of adding **isSaved** method in the **Item**  class and loop through **$items** variable in aModel.

Without using reflection, what's the best way?